# Rails + delayed_job: logging mailer output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, actionmailer, delayed-job

When sending emails in development mode the content is normally logged to stdout.  When the mail delivery is moved into the background the content is no longer logged.  Instead you just see something like `Job Class#some_email (id=123) RUNNING` and `Job Class#some_email (id=123) COMPLETED after 0.12345`.  Is there a way to continue logging the email content?

Comment: I should note that I'm using Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure about logging the content into a log file in rails, but if you just want to see the content of the email I'd suggest using [Letter Opener by Ryan Bates](http://rubygems.org/gems/letter_opener) to view the emails in development through an automated process.

Comment: Thanks.  Letter opener is pretty cool.  I'd really like to see the logs though since I have a similar setup for SMS during development- it just writes the message to `Rails.logger.info`.